# Vagrant throws error when executing 'vagrant up'

Tags: vagrant, homestead

Earlier today my Homestead was working fine and using 'vagrant up' didn't cause any problems. I tried starting it a few minutes ago and I got this error:

```
C:/Users/Robin/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 751: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError)
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:181:in `machine_config'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:45:in `machine'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:719:in `machine'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:180:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:213:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:212:in `map'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:212:in `with_target_vms'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/plugins/commands/destroy/command.rb:45:in `block in execute'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in batch'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:278:in `tap'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:278:in `block in batch'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:277:in `synchronize'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:277:in `batch'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/plugins/commands/destroy/command.rb:44:in `execute'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:54:in `execute'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:294:in `cli'
    from C:/Users/Robin/embedded/gems/2.1.4/gems/vagrant-2.1.4/bin/vagrant:164:in `<main>'
```

I've looked the error up but all I can find is people telling there is a extra space or enter in the 'Homestead.yaml' file which is not the case.

Comment: IT IS an error with your homestead.yaml so it would help if you could share the file so other can review, you might not see the error but clearly the pbm is on the file, it might call another script (JSon) which itself have the error

Comment: IT IS NOT an error in my Homestead.yaml. I removed Homestead from my computer and re-installed and WITH my backed-up Homestead.yaml file. Everything works fine now.